# Can anyone delete the '/bin' folder in linux?

Tags: linux, deleted-files

Can we delete the **/bin** folder in **/usr** directory in linux.
If yes, then what are its consequences?

Comment: the literal answer is YES, **anyone** can delete the `/bin` folder and that one person is the `root` user.  You question is very non-specific and open to interpretation.  If the entire /bin folder is deleted, the consequences are the system would not boot from a powered off state, and for a running system it would crash and/or hang immediately thereafter where the only thing that would work is holding down the power button to turn the system off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we delete the /bin folder in /usr directory in linux.

The privileged user can delete the `/bin` folder

> what are its consiquences?

An answer from :[Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/bin.html)

> The `bin` directory contains several useful commands that are of use to
>       both the system administrator as well as non-privileged users. It usually 
>       contains the shells like bash, csh, etc.... and commonly used commands 
>       like cp, mv, rm, cat, ls. For this reason and in contrast to `/usr/bin`, 
>       the binaries in this directory are considered to be essential. The reason 
>       for this is that it contains essential system programs that must be 
>       available even if only the partition containing / is mounted. This 
>       situation may arise should you need to repair other partitions but have 
>       no access to shared directories (ie. you are in single user mode and 
>       hence have no network access). It also contains programs which boot 
>       scripts may depend on.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible to delete the folder if you have the right privileges such as `sudo` or `root` access.

By convention, `/usr` is secondary to the basic system's operations.  This would normally allow your computer to boot without it, but you'll be missing almost everything else installed on it.

Therefore, the consequence of deleting `/usr/bin` is that you'll need to reinstall all software packages which are not system critical.  A full system reinstall might be justified.

Note that when referring to a folder inside another folder, you put the full path:  `bin` in `/usr` is `/usr/bin`.

Comment: What does the second point mean?

Comment: @Borris It means that `/bin` is `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is `/usr/bin`, and  possibly `bin` in `/usr`, but definitely not `/bin` in `/usr`.

Comment: On many modern systems, `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`. Fedora and RHEL/CentOS 7 do this, and Debian is [in the process of switching](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge).

Comment: @mattdm That'll probably be ok as long as mounting `/usr` works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Only `root` user can do it, of course.

Consequences would be that neither users nor system would have access to vital binaries like `rm`, `cp`, `mv` and so.